# Mongoose find method after create

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've got an animal schema:

```
const AnimalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: { type: String, default: "goldfish" },
    size: String,
    color: { type: String, default: "golden" },
    mass: { type: Number, default: 0.007 },
    name: { type: String, default: "Angela" }
});
```

Animal data array:

```
let animalData = [
    {
        type: 'mouse',
        color: 'gray',
        mass: 0.035,
        name: 'Marvin'
    },
    {
        type: 'nutria',
        color: 'brown',
        mass: 6.35,
        name: 'Gretchen'
    },
    {
        type: 'wolf',
        color: 'gray',
        mass: 45,
        name: 'Iris'
    }
];
```

Then I'm trying to empty all data in Animal model, save that array to database, log some animal data and close the connection:

```
Animal
    .remove({})
    .then(Animal.create(animalData))
    .then(Animal.find({}).exec())
    .then(animals => {
        animals.forEach(animal => console.log(`${animal.name} is ${animal.color} ${animal.type}`))
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Saved!');
        db.close().then(() => console.log('db connection closed'));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Save Failed", err);
    });
```

But when I'm trying to execute this I'm getting an error:
Save Failed TypeError: animals.forEach is not a function
    at Animal.remove.then.then.then.animals (C:_projects\express_api\mongoose_sandbox.js:89:12)

What's wrong with my code and how make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it was an easy fix.
It's need to write my .then() methods:

```
Animal
    .remove({})
    .then(Animal.create(animalData))
    .then(Animal.find({}).exec())
```

Like:

```
Animal
    .remove({})
    .then(() => Animal.create(animalData))
    .then(() => Animal.find({}))
```

So in then methods was need to pass a callback function.